# Remove double inverted commas from a string

Tags: tcl, trim

I have a line like:

```
{"a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f"}
```

I want output as:

```
a/b c/d e/f
```

basically i want to remove all " and {} from existing line.

How should I do it in TCL?

I have tried using `string trim` but didn't help.

```
set z {{"a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f"}}
set trimmed_z [string trim $z "\"\"\}\{"]
```

it gives

```
a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f
```

Comment: i have tried set z {{"a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f"}}
set trimmed_z [string trim $z "\"\"\}\{"]

it gives a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a Tcl list where the inner braces are because of the `"` characters in the elements. Thus, all we need to do is to apply a stripping command (a fairly simple `string trim`) to each element; `lmap` makes this easy:

```
set yourData {{"a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f"}}
set yourCleanData [lmap elem $yourData {
    string trim $elem \"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`string trim` will only remove characters at the extremities of a string, i.e. at the beginning and at the end only. You could use [`string map`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M34):

```
set z {{"a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f"}}
set clean_z [string map {\" "" \{ "" \} ""} $z]
# a/b c/d e/f
```

Otherwise since the line looks like a Tcl list, you could use [`lmap`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm) (Tcl 8.6+) to get the "innermost 
element of the sublist":

```
set clean_z [lmap x $z {set x [lindex $x 0]}]
# a/b c/d e/f
```

---

There are other ways to do that too; maybe a loop and `string trim` (here we only need to remove the quotes because the braces here appear to act as a quoting mechanism):

```
set z {{"a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f"}}
set cleaned_z ""
foreach n $z {
    lappend cleaned_z [string trim $n \"]
}
puts $cleaned_z
# a/b c/d e/f
```

Or [`struct::list flatten`](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/struct_list.html#10):

```
package require struct
set z {{"a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f"}}
set cleaned_z [struct::list flatten $z]
# a/b c/d e/f
```

Or if you fancy some regex using [`regsub`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm):

```
set z {{"a/b"} {"c/d"} {"e/f"}}
# I'm only escaping the quote so the syntax highlighting doesn't break, but it's not
# necessary
set cleaned_z [regsub -all {[\"{}]} $z ""]
# a/b c/d e/f
```

Comment: set clean_z [string map {\" "" \{ "" \} ""} $z]    worked thanks

Comment: in that case, you might want to accept the answer then?